# isBefore() in moment js returning false instead of true

Tags: angularjs, momentjs

The following line is returning `false` instead of `true`

```
console.log(moment('9:30 AM', 'h:mm A').isBefore(moment('12:30 AM', 'h:mm A')));
```

what am I missing here. please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

9 AM is not isBefore 12:30 AM, I think you mean here 12:30 PM.